# jQuery: Highlighting Options in multiple Select statements

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have multiple Select statements on my page and the options are all the same, basically a ranking system as shown below. What I am trying to do is highlight each option in all the select statements once it has been select. i.e. If you pick "1" in the first Select, it will be highlighted in all the Select statements.

I thought I was pretty close with the code below but it only seems to work the first time I make a selection. The end result once all the options have been used would be that all the options are highlighted with the grey background.

I am using jQuery 1.5.

```
.pick { background-color: #CCC; }

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Drop down 1</td>
        <td><select id="dd1" name="dd1">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="1"> 1 </option>
                <option value="2"> 2 </option>
                <option value="3"> 3 </option>
                <option value="4"> 4 </option>
                <option value="5"> 5 </option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Drop down 2</td>
        <td><select id="dd2" name="dd2">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="1"> 1 </option>
                <option value="2"> 2 </option>
                <option value="3"> 3 </option>
                <option value="4"> 4 </option>
                <option value="5"> 5 </option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Drop down 3</td>
        <td><select id="dd3" name="dd3">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="1"> 1 </option>
                <option value="2"> 2 </option>
                <option value="3"> 3 </option>
                <option value="4"> 4 </option>
                <option value="5"> 5 </option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("select[name*='dd']").change(onSelectChangeDD);
    });

    function onSelectChangeDD() {
        var selected = $("select[name*='dd'] option:selected");
        var test = $(this).val();

        $("select[name*='dd']").children().each(function () {
            // remove all the highlights
            $(this).removeClass("pick");
        });

        $("select[name*='dd']").children().each(function () {

            // highlight the selections
            if ($(this).val() == test) {
                $(this).addClass('pick');
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The end result once all the options
>   have been used would be that all the
>   options are highlighted with the grey
>   background.

In that case, you should remove the code that unpicks all items:

```
$("select[name*='dd']").children().each(function () {
    // remove all the highlights
    $(this).removeClass("pick");
});
```

and replace it with code that unpicks only unselected items:

```
$("select[name*='dd']").children().each(function () {
    // remove unused highlights
    if ($("select[name*='dd'] option:selected")
        .filter("[value='" + $(this).attr('value') + "']")
        .length === 0) {
        $(this).removeClass("pick");
    }
});
```

Link to [jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/nx7mN/).

Comment: @JamesP: I placed an alert near `addClass` and it got called thrice, but IE the option did not display the background.  I guess it's an IE problem, no idea how to work around that!

Comment: I agree, it seems to be a problem with the `addclass` function. It's almost as if the browser needs to refresh or something...

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      //i used another selector and add "dd" class name to all select
      $("select.dd").change(function(){
       $("select.dd").children().removeClass("pick");
        $("select.dd").children('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').addClass("pick");
      });
 });
```

You can try it here http://jsfiddle.net/R9JCd/1/

Comment: This only seems to highlight the last item selected from one of the select boxes.

Comment: It's close but doesn't remove the items that are no longer selected. The solution form Andomar below works well except in IE.